# Plot predicted time series line at specific index coordinates

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am pretty new to R and despite having done a lot of research on this naive question, I could only find overly complicated solutions to this simple problem. I would simply like to understand how to use plot() and lines() to solve the following.

I have some predicted values which I want to plot against actual values in a time series.

Using this code plots the predicted values starting from axis index 0

```
plot(as.ts(data$y[1:500]))
  lines(as.ts(output1), col = "blue")
```

However I would like it to start from axis index 251 in the ts to show the prediction in blue, against the actual values in black.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xlim parameter to specify your plots postion on the x-axis, if this is what you mean:

```
plot(as.ts(data$y[1:500]), xlim = c(251,500))
  lines(as.ts(output1), col = "blue")
```